# JS: How to create function that return list of all restaurants with same price range?

Tags: javascript

I have a program that have functions for creating restaurants and price ranges, and I need to return in function all restaurants that are with same price range, I am not sure how?
This is my code, and name of function is findRestaurantsByPriceRange, I am trying to check if range category is same, but not sure how?
NB: Filter is not Allowed to use. I would like to do it with for or foreach, if it is possible?

```js
function createRestaurant(name, address, averageMealPrice, numberOfTable, category, priceRange, size) {
    return { name, address, averageMealPrice, numberOfTable, category, priceRange, size };
  }
  
  
  function createCategory(type) {
    return { type };
  }
  
  function createSizeOfRestaurant(size) {
    return { size };
  }
  
  
  let category1 = createCategory(['Chinese', 'International']);
  let category2 = createCategory(['Fast food', 'Middle Eastern']);
  let category3 = createCategory(['Balkan', 'Indian']);
  
  let size1 = createSizeOfRestaurant('small');
  let size2 = createSizeOfRestaurant('medium');
  let size3 = createSizeOfRestaurant('big');
  
  //THIS IS RANGE
  let range = ['inexpensive', 'moderate', 'expensive'];
  
  let restaurant1 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Bulevar Oslobodjenja 2', 500, 20, category1, range[0], size1);
  let restaurant2 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Bulevar Oslobodjenja 2', 500, 20, category2, range[1], size2);
  let restaurant3 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Bulevar Oslobodjenja 2', 500, 20, category3, range[2], size3);
  
  let restaurants = [restaurant1, restaurant2, restaurant3];
  
  function findRestaurantsByPriceRange(restaurantByPrice, category) {
    const result = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < restaurantByPrice.length; i++) {
      let valid = false;
      const restaurant = restaurantByPrice[i];
      // To break the loop without it going through all the items in the array, I check if valid has been set to true. If so, the loop breaks
      for (let j = 0;
        (j < restaurant.category.type.length && valid === false); j++) {
        const restaurantCategory = restaurant.category.type[j];
        if (restaurantCategory === category) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }
  
      if (valid === true) result.push(restaurant)
    }
    
    return result;
  }
  
  function findRestaurantByCategory(restaurantsByCategory, category) {
    const result = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < restaurantsByCategory.length; i++) {
      let valid = false;
      const restaurant = restaurantsByCategory[i];
      for (let j = 0; (j < restaurant.category.type.length && valid === false); j++) {
        const restaurantCategory = restaurant.category.type[j];
        if (restaurantCategory === category) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }
  
      if (valid === true) result.push(restaurant)
    }
    
    return result;
  }

  function findRestaurantsBySize(restaurantsBySize, size){
    const result = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < restaurantsBySize.length; i++) {
      let valid = false;
      const restaurant = restaurantsBySize[i];
      for (let j = 0; (j < restaurant.size.type.length && valid === false); j++) {
        const restaurantSize = restaurant.size.type[j];
        if (restaurantSize === size) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }
  
      if (valid === true){ 
        result.push(restaurant)
      }
    }
    
    return result;
  }

  console.log(findRestaurantByCategory(restaurants, 'Chinese'))
  console.log(findRestaurantsBySize(restaurants, 'small'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). SO expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Now this does look like a MCVE to me, but I think you still need to show us that you have tried a few more things than this before I would answer. Right now all I can see is the setup. Trial and error is an important part of the learning process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) were used with the first two methods

#### Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
function findRestaurantsByPriceRange(restaurantByPrice, category){
    return restaurantByPrice.filter(({ category: restaurantCategory }) => restaurantCategory.some(item => category.type.includes(item)));
}
```

#### Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
function findRestaurantsByPriceRange(restaurantByPrice, category) {
  return restaurantByPrice.reduce((acc, restaurant) => {
  acc.push(restaurant.category.some(item => category.type.includes(item)) ? restaurant : ...[])
  return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

#### Using a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) loop

Here, you have to loop through the `restaurantByPrice` array and its `category` array, using a flag to check if any of the restaurant's category matches the one passed to the function.

```
function findRestaurantsByPriceRange(restaurantByPrice, category) {
  const result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < restaurantByPrice.length; i++) {
    let valid = false;
    const restaurant = restaurantByPrice[i];
    
    // To break the loop without it going through all the items in the array, I check if valid has been set to true. If so, the loop breaks
    for (let j = 0; (j < restaurant.category.length && valid === false); j++) {
      const restaurantCategory = restaurant.category[j];

      if (restaurantCategory === category) {
        valid = true;
      }
    }

    if (valid === true) result.push(restaurant)
  }
```

```js
function createRestaurant(name, address, averageMealPrice, numberOfTable, category, priceRange, size) {
  return { name, address, averageMealPrice, numberOfTable, category, priceRange, size };
}


function createCategory(type) {
  return { type };
}

function createSizeOfRestaurant(size) {
  return { size };
}


let category1 = createCategory(['Chinese', 'International']);
let category2 = createCategory(['Fast food', 'Middle Eastern']);
let category3 = createCategory(['Balkan', 'Indian']);

let size1 = createSizeOfRestaurant('small');
let size2 = createSizeOfRestaurant('medium');
let size3 = createSizeOfRestaurant('big');

//THIS IS RANGE
let range = ['inexpensive', 'moderate', 'expensive'];

let restaurant1 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Bulevar Oslobodjenja 2', 500, 20, category1, range[0], size1);
let restaurant2 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Bulevar Oslobodjenja 2', 500, 20, category2, range[1], size2);
let restaurant3 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Bulevar Oslobodjenja 2', 500, 20, category3, range[2], size3);

let restaurants = [restaurant1, restaurant2, restaurant3];

function findRestaurantsByPriceRange(restaurantByPrice, category) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < restaurantByPrice.length; i++) {
    let valid = false;
    const restaurant = restaurantByPrice[i];
    // To break the loop without it going through all the items in the array, I check if valid has been set to true. If so, the loop breaks
    for (let j = 0;
      (j < restaurant.category.type.length && valid === false); j++) {
      const restaurantCategory = restaurant.category.type[j];
      if (restaurantCategory === category) {
        valid = true;
      }
    }

    if (valid === true) result.push(restaurant)
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(findRestaurantsByPriceRange(restaurants, 'Chinese'))
```

---

#### To check for `size`

```
function findRestaurantsByPriceRange(restaurantByPrice, size) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < restaurantByPrice.length; i++) {
    const restaurant = restaurantByPrice[i];
    if (restaurant.size.size === size) result.push(restaurant);
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Filter is not allowed to use :/ Is there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: Why is it titled, `Array#map` when it doesn't use `map`?

Comment: also: This answer looks to be very helpful. However, we try to encourage people to help themselves in the first instance, and quick answers that are given to homework questions can work against that goal. Would you consider in the future giving more of a partial answer, or waiting until the OP has constructed a question featuring evidence of prior effort? Thank you.

Comment: I'm thinking if they aren't allowed to use filter, they're probably supposed to use a for loop, and a `reduce` is potentially beyond the level of their homework. It is correct though so I've given it a +1 anyway

Comment: @a.mola no worries. Homework questions are handled very inconsistently on SO, which is why I have a few saved snippets to help nudge them in the right direction instead of making it too easy, or closing like many others would. I prefer to appreciate the effort of everyone involved

Comment: @a.mola Thanks, but is this possible to do with for , or foreach, without built in function?

Comment: @coagmano You are right, we are not allowed to use reduce. I am trying cause it with for or foreach...

Comment: @MAlex, Yes it is. As a hint, a reduce is quite similar to a for loop, so you can use that as a bit of a guide to what a for loop should be doing

Comment: @MAlex I've added code to use with a `for` loop with an explanation of the process

Comment: @a.mola Thank u so much. But I have one question, I tried this now and I get [] (empty array) as a result of console.log(findRestaurantByPriceRange(restaurants, range[0]), even if I have added one restaurant with range[0]. Do you know why this can be empty array?

Comment: @MAlex. Yeah I've edited the code. With a snippet

Comment: Also, be careful with the category in this function, since category is actually an object with a type property `{ type: 'Chinese' }`. Right now it's working because you're checking against the same object returned by `createCategory`, but if you made a new category with the same name/type, it would not match because it's a different object. So you probably want to dig into the category object and compare the strings stored within

Comment: Also the whole setup code smells of a teacher still thinking in OO when using not-necessarily-OO languages like JS. This could be so much simpler 

Comment: Yeah @coagmano. That was what caused the error, I also added the fix to the `filter` and `reduce` methods.

Comment: @a.mola I have again same question. I tried to replace code for size, but I got error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Do you know why now I get this error?

Comment: Because size has a different schema to the category. @MAlex. Check my edits